# What does yellow tinting represent when using "color misaligned images" on iPhone/iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, core-graphics, instruments

so--i switched on "color misaligned images" to improve drawing performance in our app. The documentation states:

> Puts a magenta overlay over images
>   whose source pixels aren't aligned to
>   destination pixels

I don't know what the yellow means however. (There is a "Color Offscreen-Rendered" option that uses yellow... does "Color Misaligned Images" also turn on this option?)

Anybody know?

TIA

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Magenta overlays are caused by subpixel misalignment, while yellow overlays are caused by stretching. Prior to iOS 4, Instruments used magenta for both.

Comment: Not in the textual documentation that I know of, but it’s mentioned about 50 minutes into _Core Animation in Practice, Part 2_ from the WWDC 2010 session videos.

Comment: Link to "Core Animation in Practice, Part 2" <https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=425> and Part 1:<https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=424>

Comment: Odd - noticed the Status bar shows up yellow when you do choose this option (and with no app open).

Comment: @SnowCrash When these overlays are active they work device-wide; even in other apps or SpringBoard.

Comment: @Wilbur - does that mean the Status bar has misaligned pixels?

Comment: @SnowCrash Not misaligned, but stretched. UI elements that repeat exactly in one direction are often stretched from a 1xN sized image.